# How to specify SQL Server username/password when installing Azure Devops Server?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2022

When installing Azure Devops Server 2022 there doesn't seem to be an option to specify the credentials to the SQL Server instance that you select. Am I only limited to Windows Authentication here or is there any other way to authenticate, like with a username/password combination?

Answer (score -1):

Azure DevOps server supports only AD users. When you define a service account the setup wizard adds all needed permissions on the SQL level. Check requirements for the service account: [Service account requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/account-requirements?view=azure-devops-2022)

Comment: It does support non-AD installations, just not on multiple machines.